# Computer Hangs at Startup Screen

Tags: windows-7, freeze, boot, windows-update

I recently updated my win7 HP Pavilion p6000 PC and it sort of hanged halfway while shutting down (part of the updating process) so I used the button to manually turn it off. Now I can't get my PC working any more. It starts with asking me to choose between 'Launch Setup Repair' and 'Start Windows Normally'. Selecting the former leads me to a blue screen (NOT BSOD, just a blue screen) with my cursor but with no options whatsoever. The latter would bring me to the Starting Windows but it just freezes there.

I tried pressing F8 to use 'Last Known Good Configuration' as some articles suggested but F8 didn't bring me anywhere.

The computer doesn't respond to any keys I press while booting up.

I have been using malwarebytes and symantec to clean up the computer lately.

I also don't have any CD for a system repair.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You need to download or create a system repair disk using another Windows 7 if possible.  Information on the crash itself would be helpful.  Are you able to boot into Safe Mode?

Comment: Is there another way to enter Safe Mode without going through Advanced Boot Options? Cause my computer doesn't respond to F8.

Comment: Provide the errorcode of Bluescreen.

Comment: It's not a bluescreen. It looks like the background for the Setup Repair but doesn't provide any options. It's literally just a bluescreen with a cursor and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this and I had to purchase a new hard drive, installed my existing Windows license to it, slaved the original (old) hard drive and copied the files from my 'old' hard drive over to my new HD. I then reformatted the original (for the license). I now have 2 hard drives (Please read the next paragraph in regards to not owning the original disc)!

However, you may be able to do a repair (as per Ramhound's suggestion in the comments of OP) and although you don't have the disc, you can [download the OS](http://www.w7forums.com/threads/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-image-downloads.12325/) as an ISO (on another machine) and burn to DVD but do make sure you're downloading the same version as the licence you own.

Comment: @JemTay - He purchase a HDD you don't have to purchase Windows again.